# Using npgsql with EF6 in asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net-core, npgsql

Is there documentation as how to install npgsql supporting EF6 in asp.net 5 enviroment ?

Or an example?

Answer (score 1):

This blog post goes over using EF6 with ASP.NET 5. http://blog.tonysneed.com/2016/01/22/ef6-asp-net-core-mvc6/ In theory you just need to use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.EntityFramework/.

Use caution howerver: EF6 does not (and will not) support .NET Core, only the full .NET Framework. EF Core is a new version of EF, designed to support ASP.NET Core on .NET Core. Npgsql has support for EF Core and is available here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework7.Npgsql/  See docs here: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/ef7.html

(I assume at some point this package will be renamed from EF7.Npgsql to EFCore.Npgsql... see https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/966)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have created a new project to use EF6. 
Installing MS EF6 is not a problem and works fine. Therefore the procedure i am using is OK. 
Unfortunately installing npgsql EF7 gives an error.
Severity Code Description Project File Line Column Suppression State
Warning NU1007 Dependency specified was EntityFramework7.Npgsql >= 3.1.0-rc1-3 but ended up with EntityFramework7.Npgsql 1.0.0. 

Then it can't pull in DbContext library. 
Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @natemcmaster, Thanks for the links. These to some extend answered my questions. Unfortunately there is a problem in startup's  ConfigureServices code. 
The snippet inside AddScoped doesn't execute at all.
Any suggestions with working snippet? Many thanks.

Comment: There is a bug in installation of EntityFramework6.Npgsql. 
The default connection library is set to SqlServer. Consequently it doesn't recognise the "port" parameter which is required to connect to postgersql
Also the library is fixed to .net 4.5 and not higher. This causes problems.

Comment: hi @natemcmaster - in order to install npgsql does one simply install the nuget package? Unfortunately there is no documentation for absolute noobs like me. any advice would be most appreciated.